# Neo4j Cypher Aggregate function changes in WITH clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate-functions

I'm new to Neo4j, and having a problem with the average function.

I've got a test database of bank accounts (nodes) and payments between them (relationships).

I want to compute the average of the payments between each pair of accounts (ie between A&B, between A&C, between B&C, etc), and then find any payments that are $50 above the average.

My code looks like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:Payment]-(b)
WITH a, b, AVG(ToFloat(r.Amount)) AS Average, ToFloat(r.Amount) as Amount
WHERE Amount-Average>50
RETURN a, b, Amount-Average AS Difference
```

If I just leave a and Average in the WITH clause, it seems to compute the average correctly, but if I add in anything else (either r or the r.Amount clause), then the Average function output changes, and just returns the same value as "Amount" (So it would compute "Difference" as 0 for every relationship).

Could it be that the way I'm MATCHing the nodes and relationships doesn't correctly find the relationships between each pair of accounts and then average on them, which would then cause the error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of Cypher's implicit grouping when performing aggregations. The grouping key (the context over which the grouping happens) is implicit, formed by the non-aggregation variables present on the WITH or RETURN clause.

This is why, when you include `r` or `r.amount`, that the output changes, since you would be calculating the average with respect to the same relationship, or the same amount (average of a single value is that value).

Since you want to evaluate and filter all amounts between the nodes based upon the average, you should collect the amounts when you take the average, and then filter/transform the contents for your return.

Also, you'll want to include a bit of filtering for `a` and `b` to ensure you don't return mirrored results (same results for the same nodes except the nodes for `a` and `b` are swapped), so we'll use a restriction on the node ids to ensure order in a single direction only:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:Payment]-(b)
WHERE id(a) < id(b) // ensure we don't get mirrored results
WITH a, b, AVG(ToFloat(r.Amount)) AS Average, collect(ToFloat(r.Amount)) as Amounts
WITH a, b, [amt in Amounts WHERE amt-Average > 50 | amt - Average] as Differences
RETURN a, b, Differences
```

If you want individual results for each row, then you can UNWIND the `Differences` list before you return.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your 4th line, but it works perfectly, thanks!
In the output, where Differences<50, it gives a row with "[]" in the Differences column. Is there a way to filter it so it doesn't have those? I've tried
'WHERE Differences IS NOT NULL' and
'WHERE Differences <> "[]" ', and neither worked. It's not the end of the world if it can't, just from a presentation perspective.

Comment: ^Edit, I found out how to change the output, I just needed to fix my list indexing (sorry, I'm still very new!)

Comment: To clarify what's going on in the 4th line, this is a way to do both list filtering and extraction at the same time. For each element in the list, we apply a WHERE clause to only keep the elements meeting the predicate, and then the `|` symbol separates that from the projection of the value into the list (in this case `amt - Average` for every `amt` passing our filter).